# PHP: How to find and extract an element with src attribute in html (from url)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am currently using PHP's curl request to fetch content from a URL. After getting the contents I need to inspect the given HTML chunk, find a 'video' that has a given style attribute and extract their source src values text. Currently I get the page but how I can get this value? Here is my code to get the page:

```
<?php
$Url = 'some site';

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // add this one, it seems to spawn redirect 301 header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'); // spoof
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

The code above is working and output the page. Then in the page's output I inspect elements and I found this:

```
<div class="webstarvideo">
  <video style="width:100%;height:100%" preload="none" class="">
    <source src="I NEED THIS" type="video/mp4"></video>
  <div class="webstarvideodoul">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the src of the video in the above code, how can I do that?

Comment: use attr selector like `$("[scr='I NEED THIS']")`

Comment: Do you want this at the PHP level or in javascript (presuming that is an AJAX call or something similar...) ?

Comment: @guradio i dont know the src

Comment: @FabienTheSolution php or javascript it doesn´t matter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At PHP level :

You can use a regex with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or use the PHP [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class :

DOM

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($output);
$videoSource = $doc->getElementsByTagName('source');

echo $videoSource->getAttribute('src');
```

With REGEX

```
$array = array();
preg_match("/source src=\"([^\"]*)\" type=\"video\/mp4\">/i", $output, $array);
echo $array[1];
```

Comment: With the DOM is output a lot of errors (more of 100) and with the regex is output:Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'p' in C:\xampp\htdocs\00\get-video2.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\00\get-video2.php on line 20

Comment: I edited the answer for the regex part. I had forgot to escape characters

Comment: For the DOM part, without having a look at the source itself, it's hard to say.

Comment: The page is for pornhub

Comment: @IvanMiranda LOL, are we learning programmatically to download porn now?

Comment: @Lau LOL, is not for download the video, is just for bypass the PornHub player, lol

Comment: @FabienTheSolution yes, but is not working, the problem is that the video src is loading via javascript is not in source code. I can only view it via "inspect element" via chrome or firefox

Comment: So it's not in your $output variable. You have to do it with something else than cURL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the video's SRC as a PHP variable, you need to extract it from the string, by checking where "type" is:

```
$output = '<div class="webstarvideo">
  <video style="width:100%;height:100%" preload="none" class="">
    <source src="I NEED THIS" type="video/mp4"></video>
  <div class="webstarvideodoul">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</div>';

$type_position = strpos($output, "type=");
$video_src = substr($output, 110, $type_position - 112);
echo $video_src; // I NEED THIS
```

`110` in the above example is the number of characters up to and including the left double-quote in the SRC attribute, and `112` is an additional two characters to compensate for the right double-quote and the space before `type`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The problem is that i dont know the source fo the video. The code I needed is for extracting the source videos of 100+ videos, so this is not working for that detail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you can use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do this, query syntax like jQuery.

```
$Url = 'some site';

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // add this one, it seems to spawn redirect 301 header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'); // spoof
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html = str_get_html($output);

$video = $html->find('video', 0);
$videoSrc = $video->src;
var_dump($videoSrc);
```

Comment: This is not working, because i cant get the page using file_get_html. I need curl instead. Thanks

Comment: Try to write your own code, this is just an example because no one knows what purpose you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Use `document.querySelector()` to point your element.Then get the `src` attribute using `document.getAttribute()`.

```js
var video = document.querySelector('.webstarvideo video source');
console.log(video.getAttribute('src'));
```

```html
<div class="webstarvideo">
  <video style="width:100%;height:100%" preload="none" class="">
    <source src="I NEED THIS" type="video/mp4"></video>
  <div class="webstarvideodoul">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i put that in the php?

Comment: Inside `<script></script>`  tag.

Comment: I put the code inside script tag, But how do I get the result?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `$output` is the complete text, you can regex is using...

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\<source).*?src=\"([^\"]+)\"/", $output, $all);

print_r($all[1]); // all the links will be in this array
```